# How to append query after limit clause

Tags: php, sql

i have a query where only 5 data from database will show at beginning from database. 
Here is the query

```
  query="SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1'  LIMIT 0,5";
```

and i want to append query after user select any other option in webpage like

```
query .="and category like '%s%'";
```

but when i select category it shows query error. Can we not append and clause after limit? Or is there another way we can do it

Comment: No you cannot. Otherwise all queries will be mess where `limit` and `wheres` are postitoned as you want.

Comment: So what can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, you can't append this after the LIMIT clause, it needs to be inserted in the WHERE clause.

You're aiming for

```
SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1' and category like '%s%' LIMIT 0,5
```

I guess you only want to add this `AND` clause in certain circumstances?

If so then don't finalise your SQL string until you know everything that's going to be in it. Split it into pieces and them combine them just before you execute it.

Here's a very simple example:

```
$sqlStart = "SELECT * FROM detail WHERE status = '1'";
$sqlEnd = " LIMIT 0,5";
$sqlMiddle = "";
$sqlcategory = " and category like '%s%'";

if ($someVariable == true) $sqlMiddle .= $sqlcategory;

$sql = $sqlStart.$sqlMiddle.$sqlEnd;
//...and then execute the final value of $sql
```